# Issue with Struts2 checkbox tag

Tags: struts2

Issue with Struts2 checkbox tag

```
<s:checkbox name="user.secondaryContactRequired" />
```

Here `secondaryContactRequired` is a `boolean` type in User Entity. When I click on check box value of `secondaryContactRequired` is `true`. 
But when I uncheck the checkbox then `secondaryContactRequired` is taking as true only, but I want this value as false

Why this is happening? Please advise me what's wrong with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: is better to provide some code view rather than naming entities like `secondaryContactRequired` etc.

Comment: that is the only line in jsp. User is a entity class in hibernate and secondaryContactRequired is a boolean type memeber in User entity

Comment: i believe When the form is submitted and the checkbox is not checked, no value will be posted for the checkbox.Just have a look here since it will generate a hidden field to determine if the checked or not http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/struts-2-form-tags.html

Comment: I have verified hidden tag, value of this tag is always true, even i unchecked the checkbox. How to fix this issue

Comment: Are you including the checkbox interceptor in your interceptor stack?

Comment: I have included interceptor...Now its' working...Thanks to all for sharing your valuable solutions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have included interceptor...Now its' working...Thanks to all for sharing your valuable solutions